# Juego siete y medio JS

Tags: javascript, html, array

Estoy haciendo el juego del siete y medio en JS, de momento estoy intentando que muestre por pantalla al pulsar un boton una carta aleatoria y su puntuacion, es decir, el numero uno valdra 1 punto, el numero 2 2 puntos, asi succesivamente, necesito un poco bastante de ayuda. Gracias de antemano

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<img src="baralla/reverso.png" name="carteta">
<p>
<div id="puntuacio"> Punts </div>
<button onClick="donar();"> Tirar carta </button>
</body>
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function donar() {
    var numeros=48;
    var rand= Math.random();
    var rand1 = Math.round( (numeros-1)* rand) +1;
    var setimedio=new Array(47);
    /* Bastos */
    setimedio[0]="baralla/basto/1.png";
    setimedio[1]="baralla/basto/2.png";
    setimedio[2]="baralla/basto/3.png";
    setimedio[3]="baralla/basto/4.png";
    setimedio[4]="baralla/basto/5.png";
    setimedio[5]="baralla/basto/6.png";
    setimedio[6]="baralla/basto/7.png";
    setimedio[7]="baralla/basto/10.png";
    setimedio[8]="baralla/basto/11.png";
    setimedio[9]="baralla/basto/12.png";

    /* Copas */
    setimedio[10]="baralla/copa/1.png";
    setimedio[11]="baralla/basto/2.png";
    setimedio[12]="baralla/basto/3.png";
    setimedio[13]="baralla/basto/4.png";
    setimedio[14]="baralla/basto/5.png";
    setimedio[15]="baralla/basto/6.png";
    setimedio[16]="baralla/basto/7.png";
    setimedio[17]="baralla/basto/10.png";
    setimedio[18]="baralla/basto/11.png";
    setimedio[19]="baralla/basto/12.png";

    /* Oros */
    setimedio[20]= "baralla/oro/1.png";
    setimedio[21]= "baralla/oro/2.png";
    setimedio[22]= "baralla/oro/3.png";
    setimedio[23]= "baralla/oro/4.png";
    setimedio[24]= "baralla/oro/5.png";
    setimedio[25]= "baralla/oro/6.png";
    setimedio[26]= "baralla/oro/7.png";
    setimedio[27]= "baralla/oro/10.png";
    setimedio[28]= "baralla/oro/11.png";
    setimedio[29]= "baralla/oro/12.png";

    /* Espadas */

    setimedio[30]= "baralla/espada/1.png";
    setimedio[31]= "baralla/espada/2.png";
    setimedio[32]= "baralla/espada/3.png";
    setimedio[33]= "baralla/espada/4.png";
    setimedio[34]= "baralla/espada/5.png";
    setimedio[35]= "baralla/espada/6.png";
    setimedio[36]= "baralla/espada/7.png";
    setimedio[37]= "baralla/espada/10.png";
    setimedio[38]= "baralla/espada/11.png";
    setimedio[39]= "baralla/espada/12.png";
    document.carteta.src = setimedio;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu problema? aquí no resolvemos tareas de nadie

Comment: Para ser un juego, aún no tiene mucho por desarrollado. ¿En que parte necesita apoyo?. Inicialmente lo que haría, es crear un bosquejo para determinar las acciones (functions()), que va a necesitar. creo que también va a necesitar crear las siguientes variables `cantidadJugadores`(como determinado `laBanca`), `jugador` (dentro de esta vairable, `cartasActuales` o `cartasJugadas`). si necesita animaciones le recomiendo incrustar [jQueryAnimtations](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) o [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap). Lo demás es lógica de programación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes, generar más facilmente y ordenadamente tus cartas así

```js
function gen() {
var arr = [], max = 20, static = "baralla/basto/carta";
for(let i =1;i<=max;i++){
 arr.push(static+i+".png");
}
return arr;
}

function azar() {
 var all = gen(),
     random = Math.floor(Math.random() * all.length);
     return all[random];
}

console.log(`Carta al azar: ${azar()}`);
```